# CSS Selector with min-height

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible in CSS3 to create a selector like this?

```
#id(min-height: 300px) {
  ...
}
```

If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: What are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: I want a selector which only selects an element with a specific min-height.

Comment: What I actually want to achieve is too complicated to explain here in short.

Comment: No...it's not..,

Comment: I Think you must use jquery. because you cannot (using a CSS selector) select elements based on the CSS properties that have been applied to them.

Comment: I don't know why this matters, my question has nothing to do with what I want to actually achieve.

Comment: @Sfili_81 Ok, thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: You can add a class to elements with ```min-height:300```, then later apply specific styling to it

Comment: *"my question has nothing to do with what I want to actually achieve."* - WHAT!? - Then why ask it?

Comment: Try telling us what you actually want to achieve and what problems you are encountering... **then** we might be able to help. Otherwise we're guessing.

Comment: @user1743312 The reason people are asking what you want to achieve when we see questions like this, it frequently turns out to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). We're just trying to help out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the height based on the screen, you could use a  [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

```
@media (min-height: 300px) { ... }
```

However, it sounds like you are actually wanting to find all elements with a given size. *Unfortunately, there isn't a CSS selector for that.* If you want to do that, you'll have to use JavaScript and iterate over all of the possible elements.

Ideally, you'd want to narrow down your set of elements (like by class or common parent):

```
document.querySelectorAll('#parent *')
document.querySelectorAll('.someClass')
```

However, if you just want to loop over everything, you can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('*')
```

Regardless of which on you pick, you can use `filter()` to filter for only the ones with the specified height you want:

```
const elements = Array.prototype
  .filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('*'), el => el.offsetHeight >= 300);
```

From there, you can do whatever you want with them.

Note that it's ideally important to reduce your sets by choosing a selector more narrow than `*` because the more elements it has to loop through, the slower it'll be.

Comment: Really thank you for that large answer but that was not needed, all I wanted to know was my question.

Comment: I gave you the answer to your question: it's not possible with just CSS.